# How to read and store the values from a String (e.g.Emails )?

Tags: java

I want to read the message and bifurcate some chunks of data from that message and store it in the database.
I have been told to use NLP.
I tried using Parse and Chunker but it is not serving the purpose.
What else can we use ?

Comment: You can always write your own parser.

Comment: What kind of data is this? Is it in any sort of regular format? More detail/context will help us help you... "Extracting data from a string" is way too broad

Comment: E.g. In an email, the email contains name, date and time ,location etc.. Now I want to segregate the name of a person.,Its location , date and time etc.. @qxz

Comment: Are these any old emails? Is it in any sort of regular format? Are you just looking at the header? **Give us an example of input/output in your question.**

Comment: Ok.. Forget email..
Let's talk about SMS

SMS :Hi Eliza, you recently earned a cash back of Rs  500 . Please redeem it before 30th November 2016.


In this SMS, 3 values are important i.e.
Name: Eliza
Amount: Rs 500.
Date : 30th November 2016

I want these three data to be bifurcated from that SMS and then store in a table

And ya it is not a regular format..
SMS can be in a  multiple formats.